# MVC 3 - Using Stored Procedures to populate model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MVC. Trying out some sample code to list items from db.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var vendors = eproc_db.Vendors.ToList();
        return View(vendors);
    }
```

the above function returns all the records in the table. How do i make it return only those with status='A'

Similarly when I do edit, instead of "delete from", is it possible to do "update  set status='D'..."

Comment: The fact that you're using MVC is incidental to the SQL-related questions you are asking. If you would like help with your SQL stored procedures please post them in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your sample code has to do with stored procedures or ASP.NET MVC 3 (it is related to Entity Framework, or whatever this `eproc_db.Vendors` is), but how about:

```
var vendors = eproc_db.Vendors.Where(x => x.status == "A").ToList();
```

Comment: @Vivek Chandraprakash, if this post helped you maybe you could consider marking it as answer? Or are there still some issues?